# Subtract two strings from each other

Tags: r

I have the following input

```
#mydata

ID  variable1  variable2
1    a,b,c,d      c,a 
2    g,f,h        h
3    p,l,m,n,c    c,l
```

I wish to subtract the strings of varible2 from variable1 and I'd like to have the following output?

```
#Output
ID  Output 
1    b,d      
2    g,f        
3    p,m,n
```

#dput

```
structure(list(ID = 1:3, variable1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a,b,c,d", 
"g,f,h", "p,l,m,n,c"), class = "factor"), variable2 = structure(c(1L, 
 3L, 2L), .Label = c("c,a", "c,l", "h"), class = "factor")), .Names =    c("ID", 
 "variable1", "variable2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Map` after splitting each of the columns by `,` get the `setdiff`, `paste` them together, set the names of the `list` output with 'ID' column, `stack` it to 'data.frame' and `set` the names to 'ID' and 'Output' for the columns.

```
setNames(stack(setNames(Map(function(x,y) toString(setdiff(x,y)), 
         strsplit(as.character(df1$variable1), ","), 
         strsplit(as.character(df1$variable2), ",")),
              df1$ID))[2:1], c("ID", "Output"))
 #  ID  Output
 #1  1    b, d
 #2  2    g, f
 #3  3 p, m, n
```

---

Or a compact option would be

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 2:3, ",", "long")[, .(Output = toString(setdiff(variable1, variable2))) , ID]
#   ID  Output
#1:  1    b, d
#2:  2    g, f
#3:  3 p, m, n
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try,

```
Map(setdiff, strsplit(as.character(df$variable1), ',')), strsplit(as.character(df$variable2), ','))
```

Comment: @Sotos Yes, it could be, but I thought I would show the expected output

Comment: @akrun I am a fan of `splitstackshape`. Very handy package.

Comment: Anyway, plus one to you too.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grepl` instead of `setdiff`

```
library(stringr)
a1 <- str_split(d$variable1, ",")
a2 <- str_split(d$variable2, ",")
do.call("rbind",Map(function(x,y) paste(x[!grepl(paste(y, collapse="|"), x)], collapse=","), a1, a2))
     [,1]   
[1,] "b,d"  
[2,] "g,f"  
[3,] "p,m,n"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Dplyr**

```
mydata %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
     mutate(output = paste0(setdiff(strsplit(as.character(variable1),split = ",")[[1]], strsplit(as.character(variable2),",")[[1]] ),collapse = ","))
       %>% select(ID,output)
```

output:

```
    ID output
   (int)  (chr)
1     1    b,d
2     2    g,f
3     3  p,m,n
```